# 1 DNS 2 IPS, 1 IP for email server and 1 IP for website

Tags: email, dns, ip, digital-ocean

Hello fellow Stackoverflow users, I have this issue while setting up an email server and website to this email server in two different machines (I've been using Digitalocean's name servers).

example.com REDIRECTS to 107.***.***.***
mail.example.com REDIRECTS to example.com

I don't think I'm able to simply change mail.example.com to another IP because then the e-mails wouldn't be like "fellow@example.com"

Any clue about what I should do since they have a rigid abuse system and they would think I'd be abusing if I carefulessly changed those kind of stuff.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you have 2 different servers ? Which one is webserver and another one for mail ?

If so you should add 3 different records:

A record to webserver:

`domain.com. IN A 1.1.1.1`

`www IN A 1.1.1.1` (www.domain.com)

A record for mail server:

`mail IN A 2.2.2.2` - this will create mail.domain.com pont to 2.2.2.2 ip

And then set MX record for that domain:

`domain.com. IN MX 10 mail.domain.com` - 10 is priority

--

Website will be working from server ip `1.1.1.1`, mail will work from `2.2.2.2`